# Executing an SSIS package from SQL job

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have created an SSIS package that simply replicates 1 table to another (on 2 different servers). When I run the SSIS package from the designer, it works perfectly.

However, when I create an SQL Job as it needs to be run automatically.  but it fails with a permissions issue.

[image]

I am logged onto the to the server with an administrator user.

I have googled this and have tried a host of different things,  encrypting the password etc and trying to execute with a proxy user but nothing seems to work.

I would like to know what this user refers to here:

[image]

Its the domain name and server name, but I have no idea where this user exists or even if it is an legit user?

Comment: Don't post an image of the error(s) put them in your post. Also, that doesn't look like you're using SSISDB, which is a *way* better deployment method; any reason why?

Comment: your ssis package cannot acquire connection to either of servers you are trying to connect , it can be due to firewall . permission or even the server/ip names you are trying to connect .

Comment: I would guess that YOU have permission to connect to these databases, but AGENT does not.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.   if I run the SSIS package directly it works.   If I run through an SQL Job I get the error above.     I have tried executing the JOB as different users but  end up with the same issue.

Comment: when you say "run the ssis directly..." is that in visual studio or where...?

Comment: Also, the highlighted user I speculate is the user that the "SQL Server Agent" Service on the server is running as.  When you create an agent job and add a SSIS step you have the "Run as:" option. It's either "SQL Server Agent Service Account" or a proxy account that was setup. If  "SQL Server Agent Service Account" is selected, then whatever user is running the Agent service on the server is used when executing the SSIS Package.

Comment: But it's telling you, that users does not have the appropriate access to which ever database it is trying to access, which appears to be a destination connection.  And that could either be the Agent service account or proxy account depending on your setup.